# How does Commons FileUpload place a file in the repository exceeding the disk item factory memory threshold?

Tags: java, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm under the impression that if a file that was uploaded using the Apache Commons FileUpload API exceeds the memory threshold declared/set by the Disk Item Factory object, it will go into a repository that would store these files temporarily. My questions is how does it place these files into the repository?

This is the code where I'm testing the scenario

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
    DiskFileItemFactory diskFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(diskFactory);
    diskFactory.setRepository(new File("/home/test/bin"));
    diskFactory.setSizeThreshold(5120);

    try {
        List<FileItem> fileList = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);

        for (FileItem file : fileList) {
            if (!file.isFormField()) {
                String name = new File(file.getName()).getName();
                file.write(new File(
                    request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("UploadPath")
                    + File.separator + name));
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I set the memory threshold to 5KB and tried uploading a 13KB file. My expected result, it will be placed in the `/home/test/bin` directory. But it was placed in the upload directory path that I created for successful uploads.

Answer (score 0):

It's placed at the succesful upload path, because you are executing: `file.write(new File(request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("UploadPath") + File.separator + name));`

However, the temporary files are deleted automatically by the library... see the section "Resource Clenaup" at the fileupload [user-guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)

Comment: if I disabled the FileCleaningTracker, do I have to explicitly write the file into the repository?

Comment: No, I believe that the library will still write the temporary files into the repository for you... only that they will not be deleted automatically without intervention (But you have to try this, I'm guessing)...